# Simple python script to configure multiple numbers to a SIP Trunk

Tags: python-2.7, twilio, twilio-api

I have a huge port-in request at Twilio and need to assign 200+ numbers to our SIP trunk. The following (redacted) simple python script works for one number. Is there a simple way I can pipe in a .txt file with the 200 +1XXXXXXXXXX numbers and update the SIP trunk for each?

```
account_sid = 'ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
auth_token = 'your_auth_token'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
  
incoming_phone_number = client \
      .incoming_phone_numbers('PNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') \
      .update(
          trunk_sid='TKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    )

print(incoming_phone_number.friendly_name)
```

Comment: I'd like to help you but I have no idea how your .txt file looks like.

Comment: That would be awesome Alex! Just line by line of all the phone numbers. e.g.; 

+13306704038
+13306684040
+13306684094
+13306684070

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign the numbers under the Elastic SIP Trunk, you can assign many of them at once. See image below.

[image]

Enabling E911 on Multiple Numbers

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alan, that's exactly what I'm looking for! Now I need to figure out how to bulk assign e911 to these numbers.

Comment: You can choose multiple numbers in the upper right corner for enabling E911.

Comment: I appreciate your help. However, this method only allows you to select 10 numbers at a time. I need to assign about 150 to one address and another 100 to a different address. These new numbers are now all mixed with the other numbers on this trunk with multiple other e911 sites. Sorry if that's confusing, but seems like a script could handle this in a jiffy.

Comment: Then the other option is an API to do the assignment, Emergency Calling API - https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip-trunking/api/emergency-calling. Look at the example, Associate an Emergency Address with a Twilio Number. You can use another API to get your phone number SID's, IncomingPhoneNumber resource - https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource (Example: List all IncomingPhoneNumber resources for your account).

Comment: Following the example I was able to associate an emergency address for one phone number. I just need to run this for all phone numbers where port_request=PX3dee56328bfbb22cc2d45edb29dfaef

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible. You could write some code do loop through the Phone Number SID's that are part of a port. You could use the Twilio CLI to get a list of your phone number SID's. You can modify this CLI command accordingly: `twilio phone-numbers:list -o=tsv --properties=phoneNumber,sid,friendlyName,voiceUrl,voiceFallbackUrl,smsUrl,smsFallbackUrl > myphoneNumbers.tsv` < It outputs the results into `myphoneNumbers.tsv`. Twilio CLI: https://www.twilio.com/docs/twilio-cli/quickstart.